# Need to set parameter value and datatypes taken from URI of resful web service into HashMap

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{methodName}/{responseType}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView execute(@PathVariable String methodName, @PathVariable String responseType, 
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletRequest response){               
    Map<String,String> yesMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
}
```

As shown in code above I need to get data types of parameters passed from {responseType} and set the same in yesMap against parameter values.

```
String param=request.getParameter("id");
```

is returning null values.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted above, the follwign call

```
yourRootUrl/cheese/stilton
```

will result in these being true in your "execute" method:

```
methodName.equals("cheese");
responseType.equals("stilton");
```

I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.  Your parameter names are confusing.

Its quite simple, you have declared two string paramters, which thanks to spring can be path variables.

This is a GET request, so getParamter won't work, try using `String param=request.getAttribute("id");` which is completely unrelated to your path variables. Or the differetn annaotion [RequestParam](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) like so :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{methodName}/{responseType}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView execute(@PathVariable String methodName, @PathVariable String responseType, @RequestParam int id)
```

Comment: If my URI is yourRootUrl/cheese/stilton/{stilton}/xyz/{xyz} then method name is cheese and parameters are stilton and xyz with their respective values as {stilton} and {xyz}. I need method similar to "String param=request.getParameter("xyz") as it is returning null always.

Comment: I have found out the answer :
public ModelAndView execute( 
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletRequest response){               
    Map<String,String[]> yesMap = new HashMap<String,String[]>();
}

Answer (score 0):

> need to get data types of parameters passed from {responseType}

Its type will always be `String` as you are collecting it in `responseType` which is `String`.

```
get data types of parameters passed from {responseType} and set the same in yesMap against parameter values
```

I think `yesMap.put("String",responseType);`  will do.